# Combining subqueries together

Tags: sql, plsql

I've received a query that calls 4 subqueries. Each subquery has the exact same FROM and WHERE conditions, except the selection is different (ie: one sums up one column, another counts the number of records for another column, and some other ones also do sums on different columns).

I haven't worked with aggregate functions much but I'm thinking there's no real difference in results if I just combine it into one subquery. In fact I would expect better performance since it's only one query as opposed to 4? Is this a valid assumption?

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing the actual SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the execution plan. The optimizer may well be doing it all in one feel swoop. On the other hand, it might not be.

My inclination would be to refactor the subqueries, just to make the query simpler/easier to read.

Comment: Nicholas Carey, I refactored the subqueries for aesthetic purposes and ran the query with all four of them and it took at least 2 mins, but when I combined them together into one, it took a quarter of the time. What does this say about the execution plan?

Comment: I'd say the refactoring was an improvement B^)

Comment: So "refactoring" refers to more than just tossing a WITH keyword in the script and defining the subquery there?

Comment: Well...it sounds like you found duplicated code and factored it out. Sounds like a refactoring to me.